# WebRequest with UTF8

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am seeing some inconsistencies (from server) when using WebRequest with non-English data.

```
String strData = "zéro";
// String strData = "zero"; // this works
request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
request.Method = strMethod;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = "Sailthru API C# Client";
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
```

This is happening only when using C# while java and PHP one works as expected so, I think it may be related to the way I'm encoding the data.

Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Thaks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you having? I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Maybe your servers expects ASCII encoding?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8` and your response should have a `content-type: x;charset=utf-8` either.